# bris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:626) [coreserver.jar:?

Tags: java, regex

path resource [customerinterestsfacades-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productInterestRelationPopulator' while setting bean property 'populators' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productInterestRelationPopulator' defined in class path resource [customerinterestsfacades-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'de.hybris.platform.acceleratorfacades.futurestock.impl.DefaultFutureStockFacade' to required type 'de.hybris.platform.customerinterestsfacades.futurestock.ExtendedFutureStockFacade' for property 'futureStockFacade'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateExc

Comment: whose alphabets?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex can help :

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$"
```

Comment: how to add condition not exceed more then 10 characters

Comment: that's working fine but it works better and it will allow  string between 1 to 255 and also numeric in name but the name should start with alphabet      ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._\\s]{1,255}$